# How to use scala.js from maven

Tags: maven, scala.js

Is there any way to use scala.js with Maven. I want to use scala.js in maven based project, and AFAIU, it's hard to integrate sbt with maven.

Comment: Theoretically you can use it in maven. You only need to find the fully qualified name of the artifact as there is no `%%%` and `%%` in Maven (which justify the artifact name with scala.js and Scala version respectively)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1) [scalor-maven-plugin](https://github.com/random-maven/scalor-maven-plugin) provides scala.js support

2) global remote shared [parent pom.xml with scala.js profiles](https://github.com/random-maven/arkon)

3) gist examples of [maven profiles](https://gist.github.com/Andrei-Pozolotin/e26380fe9703a9158efe) which configure [scala.js library](https://gist.github.com/Andrei-Pozolotin/e26380fe9703a9158efe#file-scala-js-lib-xml) and [scala.js runtime](https://gist.github.com/Andrei-Pozolotin/e26380fe9703a9158efe#file-scala-js-run-xml) projects

Comment: I'm curious, is it only for eclipse/scala IDE and not for maven in general?

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, this is not directly possible so far, because there is no Maven plugin enabling Scala.js.

Scala.js consists a few things:

- A compiler plugin for scalac, which can be [enabled with the Maven plugin for Scala](http://scala-tools.org/mvnsites/maven-scala-plugin/example_scalac_plugins.html).
- Libraries of its own: `scalajs-library`, and optionally `scalajs-javalibex`.
- Link-time tools: these are exposed directly within the sbt plugin, although the core of it is in a separate `scalajs-tools` library, which could be reused by a Maven plugin for Scala.js.

As of Scala.js 0.6.0, all these things are published on Maven Central, so can be resolved by Maven. (Except the sbt plugin with the sbt-specific parts, but that's not needed.)

As long as nobody actually develops a proper Maven plugin for Scala.js, the easiest might be to invoke the [Command Line Interface of Scala.js](http://www.scala-js.org/downloads.html) from Maven to invoke the link-time tools (`scalajsld` in particular). I don't know Maven, but I assume it has tasks to invoke external command-line programs in its pipeline.

**Edit:** Updated for Scala.js 0.6.x: artifacts are now published on Maven Central.

Comment: Wow this is really painful but alas I don't have any more time to write a Maven plugin than the next guy. Drats!

Comment: Since this was written, Scala.js 0.6.x has been released, which at least publishes everything on Maven Central. Now all we need is a Maven plugin. ^^ (Or invoke the CLI.)

Comment: Do there exist any examples of how to compile and run a simple Scala.js hello-world program, that does not involve SBT? I have downloaded the command line interface, but there is not guidance on how to run the 3 commands in bin. scalajsc is pretty obvious, but I don't know how to go from there.

Comment: @Eric Kolotyluk Have a look at this document: https://github.com/scala-js/scala-js/blob/master/TESTING It's not documentation, but it shows how to use the CLI.

Comment: That document helps somewhat, but is seriously lacking in comprehensibility. The first problem I encountered is the script for Windows, scalajsc.bat, is defective. Eventually I figure out how to compile Scala.js directly from scalac. I generated the test.js, but I am stymied at how to run this. It is hard to believe anyone has ever built a Scala.js app from the command line before when there is no actual documentation on how to do this.

Comment: I might be inclined to write a scalajs-maven-plugin if someone could actually document the manual steps necessary to build a working scalajs application. Creating Maven plugins is not that hard.

Comment: @EricKolotyluk I will gladly assist you in building a maven plugin for Scala.js. Have a look at the [Quick Linker](https://github.com/scala-js/scala-js/blob/master/tools/js/src/test/scala/org/scalajs/core/tools/test/js/QuickLinker.scala) we use for bootstrapping tests to see what is needed to link Scala.js. Best is if you contact me through gitter if you want to work on this.

Comment: Hi, is there a guide to the current command line options for scalajsld? The Quick Linker link above is now broken, and scalajsld 1.0.0-M5 gives "Error: Unknown option --jsoutput" when used with the maven config suggested in the other answer.

Comment: `scalajsld -h`, just like any other command-line program. Forget the `QuickLinker`. The simplest reference for how to programmatically invoke the linker is [`Scalajsld.scala`](https://github.com/scala-js/scala-js-cli/blob/master/src/main/scala/org/scalajs/cli/Scalajsld.scala) itself (the link is for 1.x).